# all array elements are the same fgets in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file

So currently my program uses a hard-coded array like this:

```
char *array[] = {"array","ofran","domle","tters", "squar"}
```

Basically n strings of n length "an n*n grid. I then treat the values like a 2D array. So I will access array[y][x] and do comparison operations and math using the corresponding ASCII.

I wanted to allow text files of various sizes (n*n) (up to 32) be implemented in my program instead of hard coding it. But am having issues with using fgets.

My current function for getting and storing the file information looks like this:

```
char *array[32];
char buffer[32];
FILE *fp = fopen("textfile.txt","r");

int n = 0;
while(fgets(buffer, 32, fp)){
    array[i] = buffer;
    n++;
}
fclose(fp);
```

but all values of "array" are the same (they are the last string). So with the example values above. If I printed array[0] to array [4] I get

values from my code

```
squar
squar
squar
squar
squar
```

expected values:

```
array
ofran
domle
tters
squar
```

Comment: `array[i] = buffer;` just assigns the very same pointer to all elements of `array`. You need dynamic memory allocation here or maybe a 2d array of `char`.

Comment: use strcpy instead of assign string.

Comment: @aragon *use strcpy instead of assign string* No. Do not do that. The pointers in `array` refer to fixed-length, possibly read-only constant string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array[i] = buffer` just assigns the very same pointer to all elements of `array`. You need dynamic memory allocation here:

```
char *array[32];
char buffer[32];
FILE *fp = fopen("textfile.txt","r");

int n = 0;
while(fgets(buffer, 32, fp)){
    array[i] = strdup(buffer);  // allocate memory for a new string
                                // containing a copy of the string in buffer
    n++;
}
fclose(fp);
```

No error checking is done here for brevity. Also if the input file contains more than 32 lines you'll run into trouble.

if `strdup` does not exist on your platform:

```
char *strdup(const char *str)
{
  char *newstring = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);  // + 1 for the NUL terminator
  if ( newstring )
    strcpy(newstring, str);
  return(newstring);
}
```

Again no error checking is done here for brevity.

Comment: Now you left out the `return` statement.  One of those days?  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Given this code:

```
char buffer[32];
```

How many `buffer` variables are there?

One.

So this code

```
array[i] = buffer;
```

points every `char *` element of `array` at the **ONE** `buffer`.

(One fix is to do @Jabberwocky posted in his answer - use `strdup()`)

Answer (score 0):

```
char *array[32];
char buffer[32];
....    
while(fgets(buffer, 32, fp)){
    array[i] = buffer;
....
```

Look at your variables: first one is array of 32 char* pointers, the second one is a 32 char array.
In while loop, you also just assign each & every element on the array to the same buffer. Do you see?  While fgets just keeps re-freshing / updating that buffer with latest data.